# ODE integration method world VS quick in gazebo ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a really weird situation. I created both a quadrotor model and mobile robot one.
My problem is that if I use the method "quick" it does not work with my position quadrotor controller since it follows on ground (while if I set the "world" one it works perfectly). On the contrary, if I set the "world" method when I use the ground robot, it follows on the ground and the simulation crashes. Alternatevely, it crashes when the simulation starts (it may happen that the simulation crashes when the robot is falling down).

My opinion is that there is something strange during the contact ground-robot.
Every suggestion is welcome,

Neostek

P.S. In the following my world file:

```
<physics type="ode">
  <gravity xyz="0 0 -9.8"/>
  <ode>
    <solver type="world" dt="0.001" iters="10" sor="1.3"/>
    <constraints cfm="0.0" erp="0.2" contact_max_correcting_vel="100.0" contact_surface_layer="0.001"/>
  </ode>
</physics>

<!-- Ground Plane -->
<model name="plane1_model" static="true">
  <link name="body">
    <collision name="geom_1">
      <geometry>
        <plane normal="0 0 1"/>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode mu="10.0" mu2="10.0" fdir1="0 0 0" slip1="0" slip2="0"/>
        </friction>
        <bounce restitution_coefficient="0" threshold="1000000.0"/>
        <contact>
          <ode soft_cfm="0" soft_erp="0.2" kp="1e10" kd="1" max_vel="100.0" min_depth="0.0001"/>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>

    <visual name="visual_1" cast_shadows="false">
      <geometry>
        <plane normal="0 0 1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material script="Gazebo/Grey"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<light type="directional" name="my_light" cast_shadows="false">
  <origin pose="0 0 30 0 0 0"/>
  <diffuse rgba=".9 .9 .9 1"/>
  <specular rgba=".1 .1 .1 1"/>
  <attenuation range="20"/>
  <direction xyz="0 0 -1"/>
</light>
<plugin name="joint_trajectory_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_trajectory.so"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46694/ode-integration-method-world-vs-quick-in-gazebo-ros-fuerte/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Solved] The trick is to set "quick" method with contact_max_correcting_vel="10000.0" instead of standard 100. It solves the crash problem and the robot is able to move on the ground.

---

Originally posted by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) with karma: 156 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0